# Extract Google drive folder id from URL's

Tags: regex, awk, sed, text-processing

I am just trying to extract the Google drive folder id from bunch of different google drive URL's

`cat links.txt`

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/1mzr8lgf50p9z6p-7RyHn4XjnyKSvyyuE?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_7vwy0-y0BqvPOtG2Or4pvoChnZHrHAx

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1rOLhig0g3DdgB9YfvW8HiqRA6o6LxAFF

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o2J_NwHS3l1-fM71HaDN-xxres1jHkb_/view?usp=drivesdk

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0AKzaqn_X7nxiUk9PVA

https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/0AKzaqn_X7nxiUk9PVA

https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/0AKzaqn_X7nxiUk9PVA/1re_-YAGfTuyE1Gt848vzTu4ZDC6j23sG/1Ye90fM5qYMYkXp4QMAcQftsJCFVHswWj/149W7xNROO33zaPvIYTNwvtVGAXFxCg_b?sort=13&direction=a

https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/1nY48t6MATb0XM-iEdeWzEs70qXW2N4Y9?sort=13&direction=a

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M3Xp3xz44NS8QJO5XJT5DK55MohwN6tF?sort=13&direction=a
```

Expected Output

```
1mzr8lgf50p9z6p-7RyHn4XjnyKSvyyuE

1_7vwy0-y0BqvPOtG2Or4pvoChnZHrHAx

1rOLhig0g3DdgB9YfvW8HiqRA6o6LxAFF

1o2J_NwHS3l1-fM71HaDN-xxres1jHkb_

0AKzaqn_X7nxiUk9PVA

0AKzaqn_X7nxiUk9PVA

149W7xNROO33zaPvIYTNwvtVGAXFxCg_b

1nY48t6MATb0XM-iEdeWzEs70qXW2N4Y9

1M3Xp3xz44NS8QJO5XJT5DK55MohwN6tF
```

After an hour of trial/error , i did came up with this regex - `([01A-Z])(?=[\w-]*[A-Za-z])[\w-]+`

It seems to work almost well except it can't process the 3rd last link properly. If there are multiple nested folder ids in URL, i need the innermost one in the output . Can someone please help me out with this error and possibly improve the regex if it can be done in a more efficient way than mine

Comment: OP clearly posted a regex problem and needed help in solving this problem using regex with awk or sed. Please don't remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's~.*[/=]([01A-Z][-_[:alnum:]]+)([?/].*|$)~\1~' links.txt

1mzr8lgf50p9z6p-7RyHn4XjnyKSvyyuE
1_7vwy0-y0BqvPOtG2Or4pvoChnZHrHAx
1rOLhig0g3DdgB9YfvW8HiqRA6o6LxAFF
1o2J_NwHS3l1-fM71HaDN-xxres1jHkb_
0AKzaqn_X7nxiUk9PVA
0AKzaqn_X7nxiUk9PVA
149W7xNROO33zaPvIYTNwvtVGAXFxCg_b
1nY48t6MATb0XM-iEdeWzEs70qXW2N4Y9
1M3Xp3xz44NS8QJO5XJT5DK55MohwN6tF
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{print $NF}' FPAT='[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{19,34}' file
```

> `$NF`: contains last column

> `FPAT`: A regular expression describing the contents of the fields in a record.  When set, gawk parses the input into fields, where the fields match the regular expression, instead of using the value of FS as the field separator.

Output:

```
1mzr8lgf50p9z6p-7RyHn4XjnyKSvyyuE
1_7vwy0-y0BqvPOtG2Or4pvoChnZHrHAx
1rOLhig0g3DdgB9YfvW8HiqRA6o6LxAFF
1o2J_NwHS3l1-fM71HaDN-xxres1jHkb_
0AKzaqn_X7nxiUk9PVA
0AKzaqn_X7nxiUk9PVA
149W7xNROO33zaPvIYTNwvtVGAXFxCg_b
1nY48t6MATb0XM-iEdeWzEs70qXW2N4Y9
1M3Xp3xz44NS8QJO5XJT5DK55MohwN6tF
```